# Testing a get request using angular jasmine returns undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have a simple method that constructs a random url like ( https://wqwqw.com/121212
)
The 121212 is randomly generated.

```
getCall(url) {
   this.http.get(url)
}
```

in my test I have

```
  it('test get', async (() => {
    let res;
    service.getCall('a').toPromise().then(x => {
      res = x
    })
   
    expect(res).toEqual(response) // res is undefined 
 
    const request = httpMock.expectOne('a') // errorr
    request.flush(res)
  }))
```

I am expecting on call but since the url is random I dont what it is, but no matter what I put it says ''expect 1 got none'
const response  = [{ data: 'string'}]

I dont know what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your expect check will run immediately after you perform the `service.getCall`, and so before res has a chance to be defined. You will need to either ensure the test checks are run in your callback (and then make sure your Jasmine test waits until that callback is done before exiting), or explicitly specify you want to wait for the call to finish.

Since you are already specifying an async function for your test, I suggest using await, which seems to be the favored way in [Jasmine docs](https://jasmine.github.io/tutorials/async) as well.

```
  it('test get', async () => {
    const res = await service.getCall('a').toPromise()
   
    expect(res).toEqual(response)
 
    const request = httpMock.expectOne('a') // errorr
    request.flush(res)
  })
```